# Linq2SQL and Resursive Tree output

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Consider a Tree-like structure, where the tree consists only of one table, *daTree*, with the fields *intID*, *intParentID* and *strValue*. The field *intParentID* is optional, a *null* value means that the entry is the root of a tree (there might be many).

I want all entries to be returned by Linq to SQL in the form

```
Root1
  Root1-Child1
  Root1-Child2
    Root1-Child2-Child1
    ...
Root2
```

and therefore wrote the following enumerator

```
IEnumerable<daTree> RecGetTree(daTree tree, DataContext context) {
    int? parentID = null;
    if (tree != null) {
        parentID = tree.intID;
        yield return tree; //emit current tree
    }
    IEnumerable<daTree> trees = context.daTrees
        .Where(t => t.intParent == parentID)
        .OrderBy(t => t.strName)
        .SelectMany(t => RecGetTree(t, context));
    foreach(var child in trees)
        yield return child;
}
```

which is initially called with *null* and the Linq2SQL Data Context.

My problem is, that an Exception occurs at `yield return child;`:

> first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in System.Data.Linq.dll Additional information: Method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyProject.daTree]
>   RecGetTree(MyProject.daTree, MyProject.DataContext)' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

Do you have any idea how I could rewrite the code to get it to work? I am using VS 2013 and .Net 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force evaluation of the LINQ expression earlier

```
IEnumerable<daTree> trees = context.daTrees
    .Where(t => t.intParent == parentID)
    .OrderBy(t => t.strName).ToList() // <-- here
    .SelectMany(t => RecGetTree(t, context));
```

It won't be particularly efficient, but it should at least work.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Do you have any proposal how an *efficient* solution might look like?

Comment: To get it efficient you could either cache the whole daTrees table if it is a reasonably small table, otherwise you need to resort to a CTE server side and you can't express a CTE with LINQ directly.